# Is there an algorithm that can cover a regular or irregular polygon with right triangles and rectangles?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, polygons, triangulation

I 'd like to know is there any algorithm that i could use to cover a regular or irregular polygon with right triangles and rectangles?

Ideally, it would use a minimum amount of triangles and rectangles.

This is a simple example of what i' m talking about:

[Left is the inital state and right is the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ff7O.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Every triangle is either a right triangle or can be split into two right triangles. Now just triangulate the polygon.

Comment: Draw the longest line in the picture and then a line normal to that to complete the rectangle. Then draw the normal. to produce the 2 triangles  on the left. OTOH, if you would like to create polygons out Primative Pythagorean triples, look at [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812907/how-to-prove-the-sum-of-angles-is-pi-radians) and let me know if you would like to know how.