# Solving the Diophantine equation $x^3= y^2-22$ using elementary techniques

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, factoring

> Solve for integers $x$, $y$
> $$x^3= y^2-22$$
> using only elementary techniques!

I managed to show that there are no solutions using $\sqrt{22}$, but I'd like to explain this to (trained) high school students.

A small note: subtracting $27$ seems to help, but not really.

*EDIT*: my reasoning in the quadratic field was wrong. Indeed, there is a solution $(3, 7) $ that one can deduce from the "subtract $27$" trick.

Comment: It is a famous Mordell curve, and Keith Conrad has written a note how to solve this - see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjW0L7Py8nzAhVW_7sIHXyZAeIQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkconrad.math.uconn.edu%2Fblurbs%2Fgradnumthy%2Fmordelleqn1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1U6CMusKx9cVooM5pVKb0z). But you need some elementary number theory.

Comment: Isn't $(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)=(y-7)(y+7)$ an interesting factorization ?

Comment: It is! When you have a $xy=zw$ type equation, its solutions are $x=AB, y=CD, z=AC, w=BD$ with $A, B, C, D$ pairwise coprimes. If you now impose the conditions resulting from your factorization - like $ w-z = 14$ - you will get a messy system that I couldn't solve by hand. That's where I got stuck.

Comment: Setting $a(x-3)=b(y-7)$ or $a(x-3)=b(y+7)$ reduces to quadratic equations.

Comment: Where do your a, b come from? However, that's a nice observation: if $y= x+4$ or $y=x-10$ you get a quadratic equation.

Comment: There's an obvious solution(s) when both sides of Yves' factorisation is zero. Then it remains to show there are no more.

Comment: @DietrichBurde : it seems to me that the case $k=22$ is not addressed. However, it is very interesting to see such topic in a broader context: thank you for the reference!

Comment: Andrea, there are infinitely many $k$, so not every $k$ is explicitly mentioned, but you can see from the text, what to do with $k=22$; it works like other cases.

Comment: Which case do you think can be extended to $k=22$? At a first sight, techniques are very specific to some $k$!

Answer (score -2):

You may to substitute $27$ instead of subtracting it.
$$x^3= y^2-22\implies  y=\pm\sqrt{x^3+22}$$

By inspection, we can see that
$\quad\sqrt{3^3+22}=\sqrt{27+22}=\sqrt{49}=\pm7$

suggesting one solution:  $\quad (x,y)=(3,\pm7)$

For the $22$-surd alone, if $x=0$, then $y=\sqrt{22}$ which is not an integer. WolframAlpha shows that the only [integer solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3+%3D+y%5E2+-+22+over+integers) is
$(3,\pm7)$.

Comment: add $8$ then $x^3+2^3 = y^2-4^2=(y-2)(y+2)$  or subtract $27$ then$x^3-3^3 = y^2-7^2=(y-7)(y+7)$ and you have some solutions at hand...

Comment: @Gottfried Helms    $\quad -22 + 8 \ne -4^2.\quad $ I do see now why you suggest subtracting $27$.   Either of our ways require seeing number combos at a glance like reading words but I don't see yours as "jumping out" like my solution. It's a matter of perspective and mind tricks like when moon craters sometimes look like fuzzy mounds.

Comment: upps, poetasis - that $4^2$ was a mindless shot... sorry. With the moon craters: that's a nice poetic last word, tonight, though the moon not visible... thanks for that! :-)

Comment: @Gottfried Helms   You mentioned “moon tonight” so I looked at your profile to confirm that you are many hours ahead of me in Germany. I am in Nebraska, USA. My specialty is Pythagorean triples and ways to find them. My “logo pic” is a composite of triples as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812907/how-to-prove-the-sum-of-angles-is-pi-radians). Nice to meet a fellow math hobbyist.

Comment: poetasis - a very nice puzzle that with the 6 triples; well it has already been solved :-) May we meet another time again at another question ... :-)